# Scala Akka system actorRef wrapper

Tags: scala, akka, wrapper, actor

How to define a wrapper function/class `addActorToSystem()` for

```
trait Stage extends Actor
class Stage1(i:Int) extends Stage
class Stage2(i:Int) extends Stage
```

and

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
```

instead of the call to

```
system.actorOf(Props(new Stage1(123)), "myStage1")
```

---

The following does not work

> You cannot create an instance of [Stage2] explicitly using the constructor (new)

```
def addActorToSystem(act: Stage, i: Int)(name: String)(implicit sys: ActorSystem) = {
  sys.actorOf(Props(act(i)), name)
}
```

Comment: Does your `Stage1` & `Stage2` override the `Actor#receive` method somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help you:

```
def addActorToSystem[T <: Stage](act: Class[T], i: Int)(name: String)(implicit sys: ActorSystem) = {
  sys.actorOf(Props(act, i), name)
}
```

And usage like follows:

```
val s1 = addActorToSystem(classOf[Stage1], 1)("s1")
val s2 = addActorToSystem(classOf[Stage2], 2)("s2")
```

Creating actor without ActorContext defined (by using constructor) is not allowed.

The only one reason why this works in Props is the fact that constructor invocation is handled as by-name parameter thus its evaluation is deffered